# DynamodbMapper python run locally

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have a code in python something like this which is using dynamodbmapper

```
from dynamodb_mapper.model import DynamoDBModel

class Employee(DynamoDBModel):
    __table__ = u"employee"
    __hash_key__ = u"emp_id"
    __schema__ = {
        u"emp_id": int,
        u"name": unicode,
        u"address": set,
      }
__defaults__ = {
    u"address": set([u"Konami"]),
}
```

I have all the credentials set on aws.

Just wrote a small python client to create a table in dynamodb using dynamodbmapper in python.

```
from dynamodb_mapper.model import ConnectionBorg
from influencers.data_access.Employee import Employee
conn = ConnectionBorg()
conn.create_table(Employee, 10, 10, wait_for_active=True)
```

I am tryinng to run this locally . I am running dynamodb locally . My question is how do i say the endpoint name for this client as http://localhost:8000. I looked at the java code and there is a cleaner way of entting endpoint on dynamodbclient. But in python i dont see it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: check this [out](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38141537/2960555)