# How to create a DynamoDB-Local Docker instance with exported table and rows?

Tags: docker, amazon-dynamodb, integration-testing, travis-ci, dynamo-local

I got this real DynamoDB instance in my AWS account that is already populated woth tables and rows.

I need to create a test scenario that will run DynamoDB local, so I'm using Docker for that purpose.

I exported a table with some rows of my Real DynamoDB. What i want to achieve is run the Docker instance passing a .csv file or something like this so my DynamoDb Local will not be empty at startup.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if the official DynamoDB-Local supports this by default also it seems like you need a custom script that imports csv into dynamodb, However you can create a customized image for your need. So for example you can start by a simple `Dockerfile` uses `amazon/dynamodb-local` and then add a python script which will be responsible for importing csv files, so the steps might go like:

- Mount CSV in the container maybe inside `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d`
- Create an entrypoint.sh script to use it as an entrypoint for the container and also it will check if there are any csv files inside `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` in order to pass it to the python script - *code added below* - which will load it inside dynamodb, for example as below (taken from [mongodb's entrypoint](https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/blob/master/3.6/docker-entrypoint.sh#L306-L313)):

```
        for f in /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*; do
            case "$f" in
                # if csv file pass it to the python script
                *.csv) echo "$0: running $f"; . "$f" ;;
                *)    echo "$0: ignoring $f" ;;
            esac
            echo
        done
```

> - The following code is not tested or created by me, I have just copied it from the following link [Import a CSV file into a DynamoDB table using boto (Python package)](https://riptutorial.com/amazon-dynamodb/example/21917/import-a-csv-file-into-a-dynamodb-table-using-boto--python-package-), you can modify it as you see fit or build your own script Or if you have a better suggestion let me know in order to update the answer.
> - boto supports dynamodb-local as described in the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32260680/2336650) which means you can modify the script to make it work with dynamodb local

```
import boto

MY_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'copy your access key ID here'
MY_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'copy your secrete access key here'


def do_batch_write(items, table_name, dynamodb_table, dynamodb_conn):
    '''
    From https://gist.github.com/griggheo/2698152#file-gistfile1-py-L31
    '''
    batch_list = dynamodb_conn.new_batch_write_list()
    batch_list.add_batch(dynamodb_table, puts=items)
    while True:
        response = dynamodb_conn.batch_write_item(batch_list)
        unprocessed = response.get('UnprocessedItems', None)
        if not unprocessed:
            break
        batch_list = dynamodb_conn.new_batch_write_list()
        unprocessed_list = unprocessed[table_name]
        items = []
        for u in unprocessed_list:
            item_attr = u['PutRequest']['Item']
            item = dynamodb_table.new_item(
                    attrs=item_attr
            )
            items.append(item)
        batch_list.add_batch(dynamodb_table, puts=items)


def import_csv_to_dynamodb(table_name, csv_file_name, colunm_names, column_types):
    '''
    Import a CSV file to a DynamoDB table
    '''        
    dynamodb_conn = boto.connect_dynamodb(aws_access_key_id=MY_ACCESS_KEY_ID, aws_secret_access_key=MY_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
    dynamodb_table = dynamodb_conn.get_table(table_name)     
    BATCH_COUNT = 2 # 25 is the maximum batch size for Amazon DynamoDB
    
    items = []
    
    count = 0
    csv_file = open(csv_file_name, 'r')
    for cur_line in csv_file:
        count += 1
        cur_line = cur_line.strip().split(',')
        
        row = {}
        for colunm_number, colunm_name in enumerate(colunm_names):
            row[colunm_name] = column_types[colunm_number](cur_line[colunm_number])
         
        item = dynamodb_table.new_item(
                    attrs=row
            )           
        items.append(item)
        
        if count % BATCH_COUNT == 0:
            print 'batch write start ... ', 
            do_batch_write(items, table_name, dynamodb_table, dynamodb_conn)
            items = []
            print 'batch done! (row number: ' + str(count) + ')'
    
    # flush remaining items, if any
    if len(items) > 0: 
        do_batch_write(items, table_name, dynamodb_table, dynamodb_conn)

        
    csv_file.close() 


def main():
    '''
    Demonstration of the use of import_csv_to_dynamodb()
    We assume the existence of a table named `test_persons`, with
    - Last_name as primary hash key (type: string)
    - First_name as primary range key (type: string)
    '''
    colunm_names = 'Last_name First_name'.split()
    table_name = 'test_persons'
    csv_file_name = 'test.csv'
    column_types = [str, str]
    import_csv_to_dynamodb(table_name, csv_file_name, colunm_names, column_types)
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
    #cProfile.run('main()') # if you want to do some profiling
```

test.csv's content (must be located in the same folder as the Python script):

```
John,Doe
Bob,Smith
Alice,Lee
Foo,Bar
a,b
c,d
e,f
g,h
i,j
j,l
```