# Accessing DynamoDB Local from boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamo-local

I am doing AWS tutorial Python and DynamoDB. I downloaded and installed DynamoDB Local. I got the access key and secret access key. I installed boto3 for python. The only step I have left is setting up authentication credentials. I do not have AWS CLI downloaded, so where should I include access key and secret key and also the region?

Do I include it in my python code?

Do I make a file in my directory where I put this info? Then should I write anything in my python code so it can find it?

Comment: so why don't you download `aws cli` and configure it? It seems like that is a requirement for running `DynamoDB` locally.

Comment: You're asking [how to configure credentials for boto3](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/configuration.html).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to write portable code and keep in the spirit of developing [12-factor apps](https://www.redhat.com/architect/12-factor-app), consider using environment variables.
The advantage is that locally, both the CLI and the boto3 python library in your code (and pretty much all the [other offical AWS SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/sdk-general-information-section.html) languages, PHP, Go, etc.) are designed to look for these values.

An example using the [official Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/amazon/dynamodb-local) to quickly start DynamoDB local:

```bash
# Start a local DynamoDB instance on port 8000
docker run -p 8000:8000 amazon/dynamodb-local
```

Then in a terminal, set some defaults that the CLI and SDKs like boto3 are looking for.
Note that these will be available until you close your terminal session.

```bash
# Region doesn't matter, CLI will complain if not provided
export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1

# Set some dummy credentials, dynamodb local doesn't care what these are
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=abc
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=abc
```

You should then be able to run the following (in the same terminal session) if you have the CLI installed. Note the `--endpoint-url` flag.

```bash
# Create a new table in DynamoDB Local
aws dynamodb create-table \
  --endpoint-url http://127.0.0.1:8000 \
  --table-name tmp \
  --attribute-definitions AttributeName=id,AttributeType=S \
  --key-schema AttributeName=id,KeyType=HASH \
  --billing-mode PAY_PER_REQUEST
```

You should then able to list out the tables with:

```bash
aws dynamodb list-tables --endpoint-url http://127.0.0.1:8000
```

And get a result like:

```bash
{
  "TableNames": [
    "tmp"
  ]
}
```

So how do we get the `endpoint-url` that we've been specifying in the CLI to work in Python? Unfortunately, there isn't a default environment variable for the endpoint url in the boto3 codebase, so we'll need to pass it in when the code runs. The docs for [.NET](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/CodeSamples.Java.html#CodeSamples.Java.RegionAndEndpoint) and [Java](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/CodeSamples.Java.html#CodeSamples.Java.RegionAndEndpoint) are comprehensive but for Python, they are a bit more elusive. From the [boto3 github repo](https://github.com/boto/boto3/blob/a5d345edcc9ed57e18165aa617049544095c0963/boto3/session.py#L224) and also see [this great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31948742/localhost-endpoint-to-dynamodb-local-with-boto3), we need to create a `client` or `resource` with the `endpoint_url` keyword. In the below, we're looking for a custom environment variable called `AWS_DYNAMODB_ENDPOINT_URL`. The point being that if specified, it will be used, otherwise will fall back to whatever the platform default is, making your code portable.

```bash
# Run in the same shell as before
export AWS_DYNAMODB_ENDPOINT_URL=http://127.0.0.1:8000
```

```py
# file test.py
import os
import boto3

# Get environment variable if it's defined
# Make sure to set the environment variable before running
# If the value is not set, it will use default boto behaviour
# and use values from AWS_REGION or AWS_DEFAULT_REGION.
endpoint_url = os.environ.get('AWS_DYNAMODB_ENDPOINT_URL', None)
# Using (high level) resource, same keyword for boto3.client
resource = boto3.resource('dynamodb', endpoint_url=endpoint_url)
tables = resource.tables.all()
for table in tables:
    print(table)
```

Finally, run this snippet with

```bash
# Run in the same shell as before
python3 test.py

# Should produce the following output:
# dynamodb.Table(name='tmp')
```

Comment: What endpoint will be used if the endpoint_url is not defined? It would be nice if it used beta/production endpoint automatically once we're done developing locally.

Comment: @Casey, it should fall back to default values provided by `AWS_REGION` or `AWS_DEFAULT_REGION`. Will depend where you're running it, e.g. in EC2 or ECS should be injected in for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can try passing the accesskey and secretkey in your code like this:

```
import boto3
session = boto3.Session(
    aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY,
    aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY,
)
client = session.client('dynamodb')
OR
dynamodb = session.resource('dynamodb')
```

Comment: The above is correct. you can find it here as well:
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/session.html#custom-session

Answer (score 0):

From the [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBLocal.DownloadingAndRunning.html):

> Before you can access DynamoDB programmatically or through the AWS
> Command Line Interface (AWS CLI), you must configure your credentials
> to enable authorization for your applications. Downloadable DynamoDB
> requires *any* credentials to work, as shown in the following example.
>
> AWS Access Key ID: "fakeMyKeyId"
>
> AWS Secret Access Key:"fakeSecretAccessKey"
>
> You can use the aws configure command of the AWS
> CLI to set up credentials. For more information, see Using the AWS
> CLI.

So, you need to create an `.aws` folder in yr home directory.
There create the `credentials` and `config` files.
Here's how to do this:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-files.html